# Encrypt password and store in DB on android

Tags: php, android, mysql, encryption, passwords

i've made a complete - working register/login system for android, everything is over the air and server sided database, the problem is that right now my password is being saved directly into the DB ( with no ecnryption ) and i've searched tons of websites and SoF posts and threads but nothing actually helped me.

i read about md5 and sha1 , blowfish and bcrypt but couldn't understand the proper implementation of such crytography..

the connection is made using php requests. the register code is below :

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
$username = $_POST['username'];
 $password = $_POST['password'];
 $email = $_POST['email'];
 $Firstname = $_POST['fname'];
 $Lastname = $_POST['lname'];
 $Date = $_POST['Date'];

 require_once('db_config.php');




    $check_username_email = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Username ='$username' AND Email = '$email'";

 $check_u_e = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($db,$check_username_email));

 $check_username = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Username ='$username'";

 $check_u = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($db,$check_username));

 $check_email = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Email ='$email'";

 $check_e = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($db,$check_email));

 if(isset($check_u_e)){

 echo 'Username AND Email already exist, please change them Both.';

 } 

 else if(isset($check_u)){

 echo 'Username already exists, please change it.';

 } 

 else if (isset($check_e)){

 echo 'Email already exists, please change it.';

 }  else{

 $sql = "INSERT INTO Users(Email,Username,Bio,Password,Fname,Lname,Regiser_Date) VALUES ('$email','$username',NULL,'$password','$Firstname','$Lastname','$Date')";

 if(mysqli_query($db,$sql)){

 echo "You have been successfully Registered";

 }   else{

 echo "Sorry, something went wrong - Try again.";

 }
 }
}else{

echo 'Server error - Please try again later.';
mysqli_close($db);
}
```

and my login is here :

```
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
 $username = $_POST['username'];
 $password = $_POST['password'];

 require_once('db_config.php');


 $sql = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Username = '$username' AND Password = '$password'";

 $result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);

 $check = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

 if(isset($check)){
 echo 'Logged In';
 }
  else{
 echo 'Failed to login';
 }
 }
```

everything is fine except the encrytion. Can someone guide me through this ? i read that it needs 2 sides, one from client ( android app ) and one from php server side

Comment: It sounds like you're confused about [cryptography terms](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/08/you-wouldnt-base64-a-password-cryptography-decoded). Encryption is two-way, a cryptographic hash is one-way. Calling MD5 or bcrypt encryption is wrong and might be part of what's tripping you up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To encrypt the password you can use [password_hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function.
In your registration code add the following before the insert query:

```
$options = [
'cost' => 12,
];
$password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $options);
```

this will encrypt the password recived throught POST array on registration using BCRYPT algorithm.
BCRYPT algorithm generate 60 chars hashes(cutting input strings to 70 chars), so, in your database, you will need to have a CHAR(60) password field to store the hashed password.

You can also add your own salt in $options however, as wrote in php documentation

> It is strongly recommended that you do not generate your own salt for this function. It will create a secure salt automatically for you if you do not specify one.
>   As noted above, providing the salt option in PHP 7.0 will generate a deprecation warning. Support for providing a salt manually may be removed in a future PHP release.

Now that you have your crypted password in the database, in the login script you'll need to retrive the hashed password from the database and then, compare it to the entered password with [password_verify()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) function:

```
$sql = "SELECT password FROM Users WHERE Username = '$username'";
$result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
if(!$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
echo "failed to login(invalid username)";
die();
//login failed->add code to redirect to login page
}
if(password_verify($password, $row['password'])){
//password match the stored hash
echo "logged in";
//sucessfully logged->retrive all additional data you need, save session, redirect to homepage etc...
}
else echo "failed to log in(invalid password)";
```

You will find all informations about password_hash() and password_verify() [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) but consider that:

1. Password is still vulnerable on login and registration when is sended to the server through POST array. For this reason you should install a certificate in order to use HTTPS protocol to crypt the data that flow from the server to the client and viceversa (take a look [here](http://www.onlamp.com/pub/a/onlamp/2008/03/04/step-by-step-configuring-ssl-under-apache.html) for configure ssl under apache)
2. You'r not taking any precaution on the inputs so, your code, is vulnerable to [injections](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2013-A1-Injection). I suggest using [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/it/mysqli.prepare.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) prepared statements for query the database when you have untrasted data.

Comment: i tried to implement this right now, the password section and verification is working BUT it always gives invalid username - and it always prints the " Logged in " echo. @sebastiano

Comment: i forgot a not operator in the login code, sorry about that. now it should be fine

Comment: Thankyou so much, it worked great ! been looking for a way to match them since morning.. can you tell me if i can prove this security more ? ( you mentioned ) i should use mysqli , im already using mysqli. and the ssl under appache , is there anything else i can add ? @sebastiano

Comment: i don't know much about ssl ( yet i'm just a student ) and i've never implemented it since certificates ar not free as much as i know. Btw you can add prepared statements (your are using mysqli but not with prepared statements) that would block pretty much all injection attacks. check [this](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp) tutorial for prepared statements with mysqli, it's an easy concept :)

Comment: great concept, already implemented ! simple yet effective , i'm not even introducing the variables inside the query i like it !

Comment: i'm glad to be helpfull =)

Answer (score 0):

So it would be like this, while storing password in DB, Using any hashing or encrption like bcrypt,md5,sha1 and store it in Database. 
When user wants to login, again using the same hashing or encrytion mechanism compare it the value stored in DB matches with the one passed by user .
If yes,then sucessful login.

so now,

your query for insert will chnage something like this,

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO Users(Email,Username,Bio,Password,Fname,Lname,Regiser_Date) VALUES ('$email','$username',NULL,'md5($password)','$Firstname','$Lastname','$Date')";
```

And

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Username = '$username' AND Password = 'md5($password)'";
```

Then Use Bcrypt,

An example is shown in

```
$options = [
    'cost' => 12,
];
echo password_hash("password", PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $options)."\n";
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

Comment: i already tried that , but md5 is too weak and i want a better encryption method.. do you have any idea ?

Comment: `password_hash` is a right option and it has never had any relations to "md5" and "sha1"

Comment: i also read about bcrypy, my problem is : how do i match the password entered by the user with the password ( already crypted ) inside the DB ? i successfully encrypted the passwords and stored in DB but how to verify them in order to login @Naruto